# How to remove SnapHelper from a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

I use [attachToRecyclerView(RecyclerView)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SnapHelper.html#attachToRecyclerView(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView)) and it works as expected.

Question: at some point I want the same recyclerView to scroll normally, how to achieve that?

Code:

```
PagerSnapHelper pagerSnapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
pagerSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Comment: did you read `SnapHelper#attachToRecyclerView` docs? whats unclear in the official documentation? *"Attaches the SnapHelper to the provided RecyclerView, by calling setOnFlingListener(RecyclerView.OnFlingListener). You can call this method with null to detach it from the current RecyclerView."*

Comment: apparently It isn't sufficient, adding `clearOnScrollListeners();` did the trick

Comment: just tested with `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0` - you can use `attachToRecyclerView` to attach / detach the same `SnapHelper` as many times as you want

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Staring from `recyclerview-v7:25.1.0`, is enough to call

```
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(null);
```

to remove the `SnapHelper`

<strike>I faced the same problem. Calling</strike>

```
clearOnScrollListeners();
setOnFlingListener(null);
```

on the `RecyclerView` instance did the trick for me. Calling only  `setOnFlingListener(null);` wasn't enough in my case

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked but I couldn't attach it back again

Comment: the same instance? Try creating a new instance of PagerSnapHelper

Answer (score 8):

well,it's written on the SnapHelper official API:Public methods=>attachToRecyclerView:[The RecyclerView instance to which you want to add this helper **or null if you want to remove SnapHelper from the current RecyclerView**.]
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SnapHelper.html#attachToRecyclerView%28android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView%29

Comment: This is should be the accepted answer. And please note that if your app allow switching between several LayoutManagers on a RecyclerView, like Grid layout and SnapPage layout, don't forget to detach/remove the SnapHelper from your RecyclerView (after switched to Grid view). Otherwise you will see unexpected behaviour while scrolling or flinging on the Grid view list.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to keep the reference of **SnapHelper** then there is another way around as per the official documentation you can use

```
recyclerView.setOnFlingListener(null);
```

**From the Android documentaion**

> - Attaches the {@link SnapHelper} to the provided RecyclerView, by calling
> - {@link RecyclerView#setOnFlingListener(RecyclerView.OnFlingListener)}.
> - You can call this method with {@code null} to detach it from the current RecyclerView.

**Caution**

SnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView() can throw **IllegalArgumentException**

> - @throws IllegalArgumentException if there is already a {@link RecyclerView.OnFlingListener}
> - attached to the provided {@link RecyclerView}.